# Gradle override version property

Tags: gradle

Is there a possibility to override build script property? I'm trying to build jar archive of my project and I want to specify 'version' via command line.

When I have 'version' property defined in my build.gradle (or gradle.properties), properties provided via commandline using -D/-P are not applied. Final jar is always built with version specified in build.gradle (or gradle.properties) and command line version property is ignored.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the elvis operator to reset the version variable within build.gradle (i.e. if a user doesn't pass variable "passed_version" to Gradle, then it'll pick variable "version" defined in build.gradle OTHERWISE, you can reset variable "version" using the value of "passed_version" from command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gradle override plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-override-plugin) will help you with that. It allows for overriding any property exposed by any Gradle domain object (e.g. project properties, task properties, extension properties etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57674847/5562284

> Don't set the version in build.gradle file if you want to change it later on via cli.

Setting version in `gradle.properties` instead works.