# How to set project.version by passing version property on gradle command line?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I want to build JAR with self-defined version passed via command line, such as:

When I execute gradle build task like this:

```
gradle build -Pversion=1.0
```

myproject-1.0.jar should be generated.

I have tried adding the line below to the ***build.gradle***, but it did not work:

```
version = project.hasProperty('version') ? project['version'] : '10.0.0'
```

Comment: Have you tried with adding system property (`-D`) instead of project property (`-P`)?

Comment: @MisaLazovic It did not work either.

Comment: Stupid thing, but try with format `gradle [option] [task]`, not `gradle [task] [option]`, i.e. try `gradle -Pversion=1.0 build`. Any luck?

Comment: @MisaLazovic Did not work. I do not think reading project or system property is the problem, because it can be read in my other tasks. I think there is something wrong when the build task executing, maybe the build task cannot dynamic read the version?

Comment: @MisaLazovic Sorry I try system property again, it works!  But why project property does not work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are not able to override existing project properties from command line, take a look [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/project-property-command-line-overrides-broken/2330). So try to rename a version variable to something differing from version and set it with `-P` flag before command, like:

```
gradle -PprojVersion=10.2.10 build
```

And then in your build.gradle

```
if (project.hasProperty('projVersion')) {
  project.version = project.projVersion
} else {
  project.version = '10.0.0'
}
```

Or as you did with ?: operator

Comment: or:
`project.version = project.findProperty('projVersion') ?: '10.0.0'`

Comment: or `version = findProperty 'projVersion' ?: '10.0.0'` if you value brevity

Comment: or, as the answer I posted: `version = (findProperty('version') == 'unspecified') ? '10.0.0' : version`

Comment: "You are not able to override existing project properties from command line" This is plain wrong.

Answer (score 141):

Set the property only in the `gradle.properties` file (i.e. remove it from `build.gradle`). Also make sure the options come before the command (as mentioned above).

gradle.properties contents:

```
version=1.0.12
```

Version can then be overridden on the command line with:

```
gradle -Pversion=1.0.13 publish
```

Comment: This is the best answer, easily reproducible without cluttering every build.gradle script.

Comment: This answer is actually duplicate of the one by Opal on September 2015. I guess this one gets more upvotes because `org.gradle.project.version` is too long.

Comment: @FranklinYu This answer is actually more complete: it documents how to write the `version` in the `gradle.properties` (no need to test for validity of `version: 1.0.12`, or `version = "1.0.12"` or any other variants you could come up with in a hurry).

Answer (score 18):

If you move `version` entry to `gradle.properties` file you can also:

```
gradle clean build -Dorg.gradle.project.version=1.1
```

Comment: `-Dorg.gradle.project.version` is way to long :-) It's actually sufficient to supply `-Pversion=1.1`.

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the project version on cli with `-Pversion=...` as long as you don't set it in **build.gradle**. If you need a custom default value for when no version is passed on the cli, use **gradle.properties** file like so: `version=...`

TL;DR: Don't set the version in **build.gradle** file if you want to change it later on via cli.

Comment: nice, this caught me off guard, the whole point of passing at runtime is supposed to act as an override at runtime, but that's not the case it seems, gradle does not even warn if build.gradle already has a hardcoded version!!

Comment: I agree it's unintuitive. Yet again, I'm biased against gradle in general and do not miss it at all on any maven project.

Comment: In build.gradle, you're programmatically calling org.gradle.api.Project.setVersion(xxx) with your hardcoded version. If you want to state it as a property that can be overridden, use gradle.properties.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a default version other than 'unspecified':

```
version = "${version != 'unspecified' ? version : 'your-default-version'}"
```

Pass version via command line:

```
gradle build -P version=1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

`version = (findProperty('version') == 'unspecified') ? '0.1' : version`

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to be the easiest and cleanest way, without requiring a `gradle.properties` file or changing the `version` variable name.

In `build.gradle`:

```
// Note - there is intentionally no equals sign here
version project.hasProperty('version') ? version : '1.0.0'
```

From the command line:

```
./gradlew -Pversion=1.5.2 build
```