# Automatic nexus artifact versioning using Jenkins 2 Jenkinsfile script

Tags: nexus, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I currently have a Jenkins DSL script defining my release pipeline(below). I was wondering if there is a way to automatically increase the version number of the released artifact for every build, so that I can publish it to Nexus with a new unique version number, rather than having to set it manually. I have used a plugin in the past that does this automatically with regular Jenkins jobs but I can't figure out how to do so with the pipeline script.

```
node('master') {
       //input 'Proceed?'

       stage 'Checkout'
              checkout scm

       stage 'Build'
              dir('./collector') {
                     sh "./gradlew clean build -Penv=${ENVIRONMENT}"
              }

       stage 'Flyway Migrate'
              dir('./database') {
                     sh "./gradlew flywayMigrate -i -Penv=${ENVIRONMENT}"
              } 

       stage 'Run cucumber Tests'
              dir('./collector') {
                     sh "./gradlew cucumber -Penv=${ENVIRONMENT}"
              }

       stage 'Publish artifact to Nexus'
              dir('./collector') {

                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD',
                    usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD']]) {
                            sh ("./gradlew publish -Pnexus_username=" + env.NEXUS_USERNAME+" -Pnexus_password=" + env.NEXUS_PASSWORD+ " -Penv=${ENVIRONMENT}--stacktrace")
                     }       


                  }

           //stage ''
    }
```

Comment: We just use a YYYYmmDDHHMM timestamp of when the build started + the short hash of our git revision.
Now if you want to have an atomic sequential number, you're going to need a place to keep it.  Maybe put it in a DB & read/update as needed

Comment: I decided to place a file under version control and increment the minor version value per successful build. Not the nicest way to do it but it achieves the desired result.

Comment: You can use $BUILD_NUMBER and it will increase automatically, but I am not sure if it is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VersionNumberPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin) in your pipeline to set the version number in a highly configurable way.

Dumb example:

```
script{
    version = VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '1.0.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` variable in your pipeline.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239092/10721592) answer, you can set it explicitly in gradle commandline as

`-Pversion=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` (but need some pre-configuration, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40239092/10721592))