# How to override project version in gradle project through command line?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to override the project version of my gradle project
Usecase is :
build.gradle contains a default version like version = '1.0'
i want to update that to 1.2 through command line.
Like we have mvn versions:set in maven.

Comment: I found this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717251/how-to-set-project-version-by-passing-version-property-on-gradle-command-line) in a prev question. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: @LakiGeri i think that's a different use case where we are'nt overriding the version as it only sets the version and the reply says overriding isn't possible

Comment: all right. Actually I find this problem interesting, so i googled it, but i found nothing useful just this.. But I guess you googled it as well.

Comment: @LakiGeri yes i tried writing various tasks as well but once version is set its not changing.

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle

```
task myTask {
    if (project.hasProperty("myVersion")) {
        project.setVersion(myVersion)
        println "I have the build version: " + version
    }
}
```

execute:

```
gradle mytask -PmyVersion=1.2
```

result:

```
I have the build version: 1.2
:myTask UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```